# How to restrict the number of entries for a particular column in shared spreadsheet using Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create a spreadsheed using Google Drive in which some columns entries should be retricted based on given value. E.g.: I have some columns named users, item1, item2. In columns item1 & item2 I like to have only maximum 5 users that can make one entry. If more than 5 users try to make an entry, then it should show the message like you can’t make an entry.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try Data, Validation.... with a the `Criteria:` a `Custom formula is` of the kind:

```
=count(B:B)<6
```

and `On invalid data:` Reject input.